# How can I calculate all values in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making an estimate with form. I'm ok with single value type such as checkbox. It's correctly added in total.
However, inputting numbers in textbox can be trouble.
It cannot be added in total.
It should be like this: checking checkbox with "multiple pages:100×" and inputting numbers in text box, for example 10. 1000 should be shown in Total(Subtotal).
How can I fix it?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.category').each(function() {
    var category = this;

    //選択項目
    $('input[class="value"]', this).change(function() {
      var fee = [];
      $('input[class="value"]:checked', category).each(function() {
        var num = parseInt($(this).val());
        fee.push(num);
      });
      var subtotal = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < fee.length; i++) {
        subtotal += fee[i];
      }

      $('input[class="aaa"]:checked', category).each(function() {
        //入力値
        var aaa = parseInt($(this).val());
        $('.pages', category).on('change', function() {
          var str = $(this).val();
          var pageNum = Number(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
          if (pageNum == 0) {
            pageNum = '';
          }
          $(this).val(pageNum);

          var ccc = [];
          if (pageNum != 0) {
            var price = pageNum * aaa;
            ccc.push(price);
          }
          var subtotal = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < ccc.length; i++) {
            subtotal += ccc[i];
          }
        });

      });

      $('.xxx', category).val(subtotal);
      var array = [];
      $('.xxx').each(function() {
        var num = parseInt($(this).val());
        array.push(num);
      });
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total += array[i];
      }
      $('input[class="zzz"]').val(total);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="category">
    [Group-A]
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="100">100</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="200">200</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="300">300</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="value aaa" value="100">multiple pages:100×
        <input value="" type="text" class="pages">pages
      </label> [Subtotal]
    <input type="text" class="xxx" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    [Group-B]
    <label><input type="radio" class="value" value="100">100</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="value" value="200">200</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="value" value="300">300</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="value aaa" value="200">multiple pages:200×
        <input value="" type="text" class="pages">pages
      </label> [Subtotal]
    <input type="text" class="xxx" value="0">
  </div>

  Total:<input type="text" class="zzz" value="0">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your script with this code.

```
var subTotal, total;

$(function() {

        $('input.value, input.pages').unbind('change');
        $('input.value, input.pages').bind('change', function(){
            onAmountUpdate();
        });

});

function onAmountUpdate(){

        total = 0;
        $('.category').each(function(){
            subTotal = 0;
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked, input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('aaa')) {
                    subTotal += Number($(this).val()) * Number($(this).next().val());
                }else{
                    subTotal += Number($(this).val());
                }
            });
            $(this).find('.xxx').val(subTotal);
            total += subTotal;
        });

        $('.zzz').val(total);

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your advise. It worked perfectly. I appreciate it!!!

It turned out that extra functions are needed.
So, I added another script and bug happened again.
If you have time, please check it out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501974/how-to-controll-input-value-in-form

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function calcCatTotal(inp) {
    var cat = $(inp).parents(".category");
    var total = 0;
    var mult = 0;
    $("input.value:checked", cat).not(".mtl").each(function(ind, el) {
      total += parseInt($(inp).val());
    });
    if ($(".mlt", cat).is(":checked")) {
      mult = parseInt($(".pages", cat).val()) * 100;
    }
    total = total + mult;
    $(".sub", cat).val(total);
    calcFullTotal();
  }

  function calcFullTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".sub").each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $(".total").val(total);
  }

  $("input").change(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("mlt")) {
      $(this).siblings(".pages").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"));
    } else {
      calcCatTotal(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.category ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.category ul li {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.category ul li label {
  margin: 3px;
}

.category ul li input {
  margin-right: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.category ul li input[type='text'] {
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="category group-a">
    [Group-A]
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="100"><label>100</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="200"><label>200</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="300"><label>300</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="mlt" value="0"><label>Multiple pages: 100 × </label><input value="" disabled="true" type="text" class="pages"><label>pages</label></li>
    </ul>
    <label>[Subtotal]</label><input type="text" class="sub" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="category group-b">
    [Group-B]
    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name="group-b" class="value" value="100"><label>100</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="group-b" class="value" value="200"><label>200</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="group-b" class="value" value="300"><label>300</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="value mlt" value="200"><label>multiple pages: 200 x</label><input value="" type="text" disabled="true" class="pages"><label>pages</label></li>
    </ul>
    <label>[Subtotal]</label><input type="text" class="sub" value="0">
  </div>
  Total:<input type="text" class="total" value="0">
</form>
```

If we break down the operations into their own functions, we can assign them  bit easier in callbacks. This allows a lot of different variation yet we're still performing very similar tasks.

Hope this helps.