# How to controll input value in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making an estimate with form which is that calculating each value to know subtotal from each group and total of all.

Function works ok, values are added correctly in total(subtotal).
However, when uncheking parent input, its children values stay in total(subtotal).
It should reduce the children value from total(subtotal).

[input nest specification]
when radio/checkbox(named parent) has another radio/checkbox(named children) in it,
1.childern are disabled in defalut.
2.children can be selected when it's parent is checked.
3.children change to disabled again when it's parent is uncheked.

I think I need to combine those scripts but don't know how.
If you know how, please help.

#### script

```
var subTotal, total;

$(function() {
        $('input.value, input.pages').unbind('change');
        $('input.value, input.pages').bind('change', function(){
            onAmountUpdate();
        });
});
function onAmountUpdate(){
        total = 0;
        $('.category').each(function(){
            subTotal = 0;
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked, input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('aaa')) {
                    subTotal += Number($(this).val()) * Number($(this).next().val());
                }else{
                    subTotal += Number($(this).val());
                }
            });
            $(this).find('.xxx').val(subTotal);
            total += subTotal;
        });
        $('.zzz').val(total);
}

$(function(){
    $('.category').each(function(){
      var category = this;
      //デフォルト　children選択不可
      $('input[name="children"]').prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
      $(this).find('input[name="parent"]').change(function(){
        //parentがチェックされたら直下のchildrenのみチェック可
        if ($('input[name="parent"]', category).prop("checked")) {
          $('input[name="children"]' , category).prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $('input[name="children"]', category).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

#### html

```
<form action="">
    <div class="category">
      [Group-A]
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="100">100</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="200">200</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="value" value="300">300</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="parent" class="aaa" value="100">multiple pages:100×
        <input type="text" name="children" value="children" class="pages">pages
        </label> [Subtotal]
      <input type="text" class="xxx" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      [Group-B]
      <label><input type="radio" class="value" value="100">100</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="value" value="200">200</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="value" value="300">300</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="parent" class="aaa" value="200">multiple pages:200×
        <input type="text" name="children" value="children" class="pages">pages
        </label> [Subtotal]
      <input type="text" class="xxx" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="category"> 
      [Group-C]
      <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="parent" class="parent">Yes</label>　
      <ul>
        <li><label><input type="radio" class="value children" value="100" name="children">100 children</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" class="value children" value="200" name="children">200 children</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" class="value children" value="300" name="children">300 children</label></li>
      </ul>

      <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="parent" class="parent">No</label>　
      [Subtotal]<input type="text" class="xxx" value="0">
    </div>
    Total:<input type="text" class="zzz" value="0">
  </form>
```

Comment: add `onAmountUpdate()` to the end of the last function(the one which enables or disables the input fields) it works to update the total again, after the `if` statement

Comment: worked perfectly! thanks a lot!!

Comment: please mark my answer as correct ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `onAmountUpdate()` to the end of the last function(the one which enables or disables the input fields) it works to update the total again, after the if statement